# how do i prioritize which column to show up first when resizing my browser?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, resize, multiple-columns

i have a website https://nestofthoughts.com/

on my homepage, i have two columns and alternate between text/picture on each row. (text first, then picture second on one row) and then on the next row, its reversed.

however when i resize smaller on my browser or on mobile, this pattern also follows but it becomes confusing for the user. is there a way to make my text always appear above or below the picture when i resize past a breakpoint?

like adding a css class to the individual columns? or its parent container?

******************************************** update

hmmmmm what i did was this.

```
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .wp-block-getwid-section:nth-child(even) .wp-block-columns.reverse-order .wp-block-column:first-child {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

i put a specific class called reverse-order. i put no spaces between wp-block-columns and that selector so it should select all elements with both that name. and then look for .wp-block-column:first-child.

is my logic wrong?

Comment: Yeah, this is a common problem. When I work with page builders, they usually have a row option like "Inverted device order" to solve the issue. But if it is not available for OceanWP then I can write a custom CSS solution for you.

Comment: ah thanks for your offer! im in the midst of debugging mine at the moment..... hopefully it comes to light whats wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for your layout:

1. Text-image on mobile:

```css
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .single-page-article .wp-block-getwid-section:nth-child(even) .wp-block-columns .wp-block-column:first-child {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

2. Image-text on mobile:

```css
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .single-page-article .wp-block-getwid-section:nth-child(odd) .wp-block-columns .wp-block-column:first-child {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you check out my edit? your code definitely works, but it selects a bit too many things and changes my other galleries a bit. i modified your code very slightly but it doesnt seem to work. not sure why

Comment: hmmm? im not sure what you mean. i see the reverse-order class when i inspect the element.

is it possible to make your code only run on my homepage? i thought by adding a specific class, reverse-order, that only exists on the home page that it would do the trick

Comment: ` im not sure what you mean.` - YOUR css code is NOT EXISTING on page. I have no idea how this can be interpreted otherwise)))

Comment: your code works flawlessly!
it was some of my other code that was affecting it. 

thanks for your solutions! it was really helpful and i got to study some bit of css selectors cause of your code! i appreciate your help and marked your answer as chosen.